# How pass array and variables to view in codigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, templates, variable-assignment

i want to pass an array and two variables to my view my array is passed in views successfully but the two variable is undefined.can anyone help me how to pass those values to view.i tried indexing,then the model doesn't work.

my controller

```
$Semister=$this->input->post('Semister');
    $Dept=$this->input->post('Dept');
    $this->load->model('Upload_Result_Model');
    $data['subjects']=$this->Upload_Result_Model->getAllSubjects($Semister,$Dept);
    $data['student']=$this->Upload_Result_Model->getAllStudent($Semister,$Dept);
    $this->load->view('Faculty/upload_mid_result',$data,$Dept,$Semister);
```

my view

```
<h3>Department: <?php echo $Dept;?></h3> //error Undefined variable: Dept
<h3>Semister: <?php echo $Semister;?></h3> ////error Undefined variable: Dept
```

can ayone help me fixing this problem.everything works fine except $dept and $Semister.
Thanks i advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$data['Semister'] =$this->input->post('Semister');
$data['Dept']     =$this->input->post('Dept');
$this->load->model('Upload_Result_Model');
$data['subjects']=$this->Upload_Result_Model->getAllSubjects($data['Semister'],$data['Dept']);
$data['student']=$this->Upload_Result_Model->getAllStudent($data['Semister'],$data['Dept']);
$this->load->view('Faculty/upload_mid_result',$data);
```

You can access all the variables directly in view like how you are accessing now.

Comment: i tried so but in this case i get an error from model.it says its an array and it can't perform the where function.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller use `$data['semister'] = $Semister` and `$data['dept'] = $Dept`

Comment: I mean after calling the Model functions, just right before calling the View.

Answer (score 0):

Sending data to view is easy

```
$this->load->model('Upload_Result_Model');

$semister   =   $this->input->post('Semister');
$Dept       =   $this->input->post('Dept');

$data['semister']   =   $semister;
$data['dept']       =   $Dept;
$data['subjects']   =   $this->Upload_Result_Model->getAllSubjects($Semister,$Dept);
$data['student']    =   $this->Upload_Result_Model->getAllStudent($Semister,$Dept);

$this->load->view('Faculty/upload_mid_result',$data);
```

`$data` array is applied php extract in view method and you can use indexes of array at view like this

```
echo $semister;
echo '<br>';
echo $dept;
echo '<br>';

echo '<pre>';   
print_r($subjects);
echo '<pre>';   
print_r($student);
```